# r.cross: max number of input map layers?

Tags: grass-gis, documentation

r.cross serves for combining multiple maps.
The current docu (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass83/manuals/r.cross.html) states in section Parameters:

> Names of 2-30 input raster maps

However, further down below, it says

> At least two, but not more than ten, input map layers must be specified

When running an example on GRASS 8.2.1 with 15 (same) input layers

> r.cross input="dem,dem,dem,dem,dem,dem,dem,dem,dem,dem,dem,dem,dem,dem,dem" output=cross_result

the resulting map cross_result correctly has 15 categories when looked at in r.category, so apparently 10 is not a hard limit.

Is there any reason I should not use more than 10 maps, or is "ten" just a typo in the docu?

Answer (score 1):

I think that requirement is in relation to this sentence further down in `options`...`The program will be run non-interactively if the user specifies the names of between 2-10 raster map layers be used as input`

Comment: It's outdated documentation, fixed in https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/pull/3294.

Comment: The update will be published with GRASS GIS 8.3.2 (and later).